# restrict class type of annotation

Tags: java, android, annotations

is there any `ClassDef` like `IntDef` in `annotation` to restrict the type of `annotation` as my example below?

```
@ClassDef({
    Integer, String, Long
})
public @interface MyRestrictedData {
}
```

As a result, I can use it as: `public void showData(@MyRestrictedData Object myData)`

Comment: You may need to wrtie your own annotation processor. What is your actual use case? I think you can do it with method overload.

Comment: @zhh yes, you're right about overload. However, I want to find an easier way to do it without overload. P/s: I have few functions which used the restricted data above. If it's overload, I have to write a lot of overload functions.

Answer (score 1):

This reqirement **CAN'T** be resolve by annotation processor.

It can only do by runtime container, like Spring.

But in fact, the container is just help you check it by proxy. Why can't you do it by yourself? Like this:

```
public class MyRestrictedData {
  public static void check(Object o){
    if(!(String.class.isInstance(o) || Integer.class.isInstance(o) || Long.class.isInstance(o)))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be String, Integer or Long.");
  }
}

public void showData(Object myData) {
  MyRestrictedData.check(myData);
  // then do your work
}
```

#### EDIT

If you really want check in compile period, the only way is what zhh said, override your method. I don't know what logic need handle `String`, `Integer` and `Long` together. But if you really need, you can do:

```
public void showData(String s){
  showData((Object)s);
}

public void showData(Integer i){
  showData((Object)i);
}

public void showData(Long l){
  showData((Object)l).
}

private void showData(Object o){
  // do your work here, note this method is PRIVATE
}
```

Comment: Sure I can do it. However, I want to notify other dev from the time they call the function `showData` not after then `run` the application.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc You can't let your `Object` parameter only accept specific types in compile period. I have edited my answer.